# Verify my PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy file, please?

Tags: ios, privacy-manifest

I made PrivacyInfo file using Apple documentation. I sent to App Store Connect, and I still receive this from Apple:

> Although submission for App Store review was successful, you may want to correct the following issues in your next submission for App Store review. Once you've corrected the issues, upload a new binary to App Store Connect.
>
> ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Some” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories:
>
> NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime.
>
> While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
>
> ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Some” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories:
>
> NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp.
>
> While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
>
> ITMS-91053: Missing API declaration - Your app’s code in the “Some” file references one or more APIs that require reasons, including the following API categories:
>
> NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults.
>
> While no action is required at this time, starting May 1, 2024, when you upload a new app or app update, you must include a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes array in your app’s privacy manifest to provide approved reasons for these APIs used by your app’s code. For more details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
>
> Apple Developer Relations

This is my manifest file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryDiskSpace</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
          <string>7D9E.1</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryFileTimestamp</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
          <string>C617.1</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
          <string>CA92.1</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPIType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategorySystemBootTime</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons</key>
        <array>
          <string>35F9.1</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSPrivacyTracking</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypes</key>
    <array>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePreciseLocation</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeCoarseLocation</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeProductPersonalization</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeName</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeEmailAddress</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePhoneNumber</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePaymentInfo</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePhotosorVideos</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeAudioData</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeUserID</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeDeviceID</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeThirdPartyAdvertising</string>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeDeveloperAdvertising</string>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAppFunctionality</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeProductInteraction</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeAdvertisingData</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeThirdPartyAdvertising</string>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeDeveloperAdvertising</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
      <dict>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataType</key>
        <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeCrashData</string>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeLinked</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypeTracking</key>
        <false/>
        <key>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposes</key>
        <array>
          <string>NSPrivacyCollectedDataTypePurposeAnalytics</string>
        </array>
      </dict>
    </array>
    <key>NSPrivacyTrackingDomains</key>
    <array/>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

What is wrong in this file? File manifest is created in root of project (in the same place where are Info.plist etc.)

[image: Added to app bundle]

Answer (score -2):

Your PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy is added to App Bundle in "Target Membership"?

Comment: Yes, is Added to App Bundle